# Q: Change notification icon in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I configured the application icon (Image 1), but the notification icon (Notification sent via Firebase) shows a gray rectangle (Image 2).
What is the procedure for changing the notification icon image (Image 2) via Android Studio 2.3 or via script?

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.studioshow.studioshow">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In manifest file. Set meta data. 
Following code is my case.

```
   <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"  >
        <activity
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/whitechoke" />

    </application>
```

Comment: After including the meta date, the icon and color were changed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** My answer is not relevant: I did not read about the `Firebase` messaging part.

---

Simply use [setSmallIcon(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)), provided by [NotificationBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) and its `Compat` counterpart.

You can retrieve the icon from your `resource` folder by passing, e.g.
`R.drawable.my_icon` as parameter.