# How to change notification badge Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have setup Firebase cloud messaging for my app, but the icon is not changing to what I need it to be. I have looked at the Developer Documents, as well as followed this post : [Q Change notification icon in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821916/q-change-notification-icon-in-android-studio) but still it has not changed. I want to change the icon for firebase as well as every notification that is shown by the app, please help!

[image: Notification]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer should work for Firebase notifications: [Q Change notification icon in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821916/q-change-notification-icon-in-android-studio)

For notifications that you create yourself, just use `Notification.Builder#setSmallIcon/setLargeIcon` :

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         ...
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .build();
```